# Function requires a double pointer and uses a representation of 2D array inside

Tags: c

I'm trying to use a function that requires as input a double pointer **B, and inside the function it uses a 2D array representation of the pointer, I keep getting `segmentation fault error` no matter how much memory I allocate to the pointer. Here is a reproducible example.
Thanks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Bk(float **B) {
    int n=2;
    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = n-1; j >= 0; j--){
            printf("i: %d, j: %d\n", i, j);
            printf("B: %f\n", B[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    int n=2;
    float *B;
    B = (float *) malloc((n*n)*sizeof(float));
    B[0]=0; B[1]=1; B[2]=2; B[3]=3;
    Bk(&B);
}
```

Output:

```
i: 2, j: 2
B: 55641428.000000
i: 2, j: 1
B: 26.942034
i: 1, j: 2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Taking the address of `B` when passing to `Bk()` doesn't mean you can use 2D indexes that way; Inside `Bk()`, the value `B[0]` holds the address of the entire float array, and `B[1]` doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: at the end of the day, Bk gets an address as parameter, whether it is float* float** etc. is nothing else than a starting address for whatever you passed to the Bk function. How the Bk interprets that is up to that function. float** implies an array of pointers to float however in reality you can pass anything..that is the beauty - or scary part of C - depending who you ask

Answer (score 3):

The function `Bk` expects the parameter `B` to be an array of pointers, each of which points to an array of `float`.  But that's not what you're passing to it.   You're passing a pointer to a single array of `float`.

You need to redefine `B` in `main` to be an `float **`, allocate space for the array of pointers, then allocate space for each subarray.

```
int n=2, i;
float **B;
B = malloc(n * sizeof(float*));
for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
    B[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(float));
}
B[0][0]=0; B[0][1]=1; B[1][0]=2; B[1][1]=3;
Bk(B);
for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
    free(B[i]);
}
free(B);
```

Comment: This works, Thanks! I should also do the loops inside the function for this case to n-1, `i=n-1; ...`

Comment: @AnasBELFADIL Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: Done, didn't know about this before ^^" still a newbie here

Comment: @AnasBELFADIL Can you check again?  It didn't seem to register.

Comment: You mix ints and floats in your answer.

Comment: don't forget to free memory : `for (i=0;i<n;i++) {  free(B[i]); }; free (B);`